# Convert string to Date

Tags: java

I have String

```
String ackwardDate="2012-10-30T19:14:58";
```

i need to convert to date format.then tried like this

```
     ackwardDate=ackwardDate.replace("T", " ");
           SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");


            try {

                Date date = formatter.parse(ackwardDate);
                System.out.println(date);
                System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

it working fine. Is there any other method?

Comment: I think C# is not right tag here.

Comment: @Soner Gönül It's Java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ISO8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: Your string is in standard format, ISO 8601. Search for "joda" and "8601" to find many answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the `T` in your date format. And also looking at your ackwardDate string, you need to use `HH` instead of `hh` as it has the 24-hour format and that is represented by `H`.

```
String ackwardDate="2012-10-30T19:14:58";
// ackwardDate=ackwardDate.replace("T", " "); // Not needed anymore
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) docs should help you understand more about the patterns available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
```

and do not replace the character 'T'

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't want `T` with your resulted date and time so only you used `replace()` method. Replace `T` with `space` is simple and good solution only instead you can try with this if you don't want to use `ackwardDate=ackwardDate.replace("T", " ")` instead you can get date object(`Date date = formatter.parse(str)`) for `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` and from that `date` object you can get `yyyy-MM-dd` separately and `HH:mm:ss` or `hh:mma`. Use `date` object as your requirement.

```
        String str = "2012-10-30T19:14:58"; 
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat formatterDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat formatterTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date date = formatter.parse(str);
            System.out.println(date);
            System.out.println("Complete Date: "+formatter.format(date));
            System.out.println("Date: "+formatterDate.format(date));
            System.out.println("Time: "+formatterTime.format(date));
            System.out.println("Date And Time: "+formatterTime.format(date)+" "+formatterTime.format(date));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that always you will have the same format of date string you are having, then keep using SimpleDateFormat otherwise it is better to split your string and create using GregorianCalendar

`String ackwardDate="2012-10-30T19:14:58";

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date dt=df.parse(ackwardDate);
        System.out.println(dt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```